# Query Data Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, realm, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query data in Firestore and saving query data to realm, but it always error. I thinks that the problem is that I got the query result after create realm objects. Anyone have Idea how to manage this, I don't know how to fix this problem.

This is my code

```
    collectionReference = db.collection("Lookup");
    Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("email", email );

    Log.d("Initial Lookup: ", "begin");
    Log.d("Initial Lookup: ", email);

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Log.d("Doc Snapshot: ", "Complete Query!");
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("Doc Snapshot: ", "Success Query!");
                int i = 0;
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult()){
                    Log.d("Doc Snapshot: ", "-----------------------");
                    Log.d("Doc Snapshot: ", "" + doc.getData());
                    i++;

                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    LookupModel model = realm.createObject(LookupModel.class);
                    model.setEmail(email);
                    model.setId(String.valueOf(doc.getData().get("id")) );
                    Log.d("id", String.valueOf(doc.getData().get("id")) );
                    model.setSimkey(Simkey);
                    Log.d("key", Simkey);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                }
                Log.d("Document Query Count: ", "" + i);
            } else{
                Log.d("Error Snapshot: ", String.valueOf(task.getException()) );
            }
        }

    });
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    LookupModel mod = realm.where(LookupModel.class)
            .equalTo("simkey", key)
            .findFirst();
    String id = mod.getId();
```

The problem always occur because this line

```
String id = mod.getId();
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: null pointer exception

Comment: So it sounds like `mod` is null then. I don't know enough about Realm to help there. But it sounds like the problem is unrelated to Firebase, so I'm going to remove those tags. It seems to be the problem might just be in the last 5 lines of code that you shared, but then depends on your Realm data model, the `LookupModel` and value of `key`. It might help if you [create a **minimal** complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).